# What are the elements of $\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z∗\Bbb Z_2?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, free-product

What are the elements of the following groups?

(1) $\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z_2$ ,

(2) $\Bbb Z∗\Bbb Z_2$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The elements of $Z\oplus Z_2$ are pairs $(a,b)$ with $a\in Z$ and $b\in Z_2$. The elements of $Z*Z_2$ are words $a_1a_2\dots a_m$ with each $a_i$ belonging to either $Z$ or $Z_2$.

Comment: Did you mean the elements of $(\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z_2)\oplus(\Bbb Z\ast\Bbb Z_2)$?

Comment: No, I meant a) Elements of the group Z⊕Z2.    b) elements of Z∗Z2

Comment: Please don't change the question entirely, @MyownGait.

Comment: Also, please accept the current answer by clicking the $\checkmark$ button (if it is sufficient for you).

Comment: What's $\Bbb Z_2$ here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z_2$ are pairs $(z, [w]_2)$ for $z\in\Bbb Z$ and $[w]_2\in\Bbb Z_2$, whereas since $$\langle a, b\mid b^2\rangle$$ is a presentation for $G=\Bbb Z\ast\Bbb Z_2$, the elements of $G$ are of the form $\prod_{i=0}^na^{\alpha_i}b^{\varepsilon_i}$, where $n\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$, $\alpha_i\in \Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ (with $\alpha_0$ potentially $0$), and $\varepsilon_i=1$ (with $\varepsilon_n$ potentially $0$).

Comment: Why the downvote? This is answer is correct!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I hazard a guess that the downvoter things this question is of such low quality that we should refrain from answering it, and instead try and help the asker to improve their question first. You may disagree with such a voting policy, but the place to discuss them is meta. And each user is welcome to use any voting policy they choose (there are very few rules re voting).

Comment: Mind you, I also think this question should not have been answered. But I don't see a need to downvote your answer.

Comment: Is $\Bbb Z_2=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z_2=\Bbb Z_2$?